# Halt execution for x seconds after initial AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to run a series of AJAX calls however because the 1st call
which stops a server process can take 60 seconds before the server stops,
I need to be able to wait the 60 seconds before the 2nd call runs the start process

However setTimeout doesnt seem to halt the execution

Here is my code

Ajax

```
$.ajax(
  'test2.php?action=stop', {
    success: function(data) {
      $('#msg').append("Server Stopping... Please Wait<br>")
      //$('#msg').append(data)
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Stop Server Delay 
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#msg').append("...<br>")
      }, 5000);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#msg').append("Still Waiting...<br>")
      }, 10000);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#msg').append("...<br>")
      }, 15000);
      //
      setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax(
          'test2.php?action=restart', {
            success: function(data2) {
              $('#msg').append(data2)
            },
          });
      }, 60000);
    }
  }
);
```

However it still seems to be calling the test2.php page while the process is running to shut the server down and is causing a conflict

Comment: `setTimeout()` is asynchronous. It returns immediately, but the callback is called after the timeout. So the second AJAX call shouldn't happen until 60 seconds after the first one completes.

Comment: Any ideas why it is calling before the 60 second delay ?

Comment: No idea. Like I said, it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Are the other messages waiting the appropriate amount of time?

Comment: Yes they are all ok .. Just increased the delay time to 5 mins on the restart call to see if that is the issue

Comment: Are you sure the second `$.ajax` is inside `function()`? You would have the problem you describe if you wrote `setTimeout($.ajax(...), 60000)`

Comment: Ok so found the issue .. the delay time wasnt long enough..

Comment: So it was actually waiting 60 seconds? I thought the point of the question was that it wasn't waiting at all.

Comment: Because the server kept returning the error "process currently running" I assumed it wasnt as it usually only takes 20 seconds max to kill the process so 60 seconds should have been more than enough

Comment: You can see the actual times in the DevTools Network tab.

Comment: Wasnt aware of that.. noted for the future.. thanks